# Read from an arbitrary fd of a running process

Tags: pipe, file-descriptors

I have two processes `A` and `B`, communicating over a pipe. I would like to be able to read from that pipe, using `lsof` I can easily find the right fd, unfortunately `tail -f /proc/$pid/fd/$fd` doesn't seem to be able to read from that pipe. Is there any way I could do this?

Usually I'd use `strace` for this task but unfortunately I can't here (http://blog.johngoulah.com/2016/03/running-strace-in-docker/, I assume this might be an issue if the answers suggests some `gdb` trick).

Comment: Do you mean you want to snoop on what A is sending to B, or do you mean that you want to read data instead of B?

Comment: I just want to snoop, but if the only way is to 'steal' the pipe from B, I'm happy to do that too.

Comment: `tail /proc/$pid/fd/$fd` would steal some of the data: each byte would (somewhat unpredictably) go to either B or `tail`, not both. For snooping, ptrace is the normal way. If it's disabled, snooping may be impossible. Can you modify the way B is executed (e.g. `LD_PRELOAD`)? Can you insert a relay between A and B?

Comment: I guess `LD_PRELOAD` would do the trick though this is more involved than I was hoping (probably because as you said, the correct/common way is ptrace).